# Tensorflow tape.gradient() returning None on style transfer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on deep learning styler transfer using vgg19, but I can't get my optimizer to work, as my gradient won't compute and tape.gradient returns none. I can't find any issues in my code. Here's the code for loss and gradient tape.

the "image" is a TensorFlow tensor

**Loss**

```
image_features = get_features(image, model)
style_features = get_features(style, model)
content_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(image_features[3]-content_features[3]))
content_loss *= content_weight

style_loss = 0
style_weights = [1.0, 0.8, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1]
for w in range(len(style_weights)):
  gram_image = gram_matrix(image_features[w])
  gram_style = gram_matrix(style_features[w])
  style_loss += style_weights[w] * tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(gram_image - gram_style))

print("content_loss: ", content_loss, "style_loss: ", style_loss)
loss = content_loss + style_loss
grad = get_gradient(loss, image)
```

**gram_matrix**

```
def gram_matrix(tensor):
    channels = tensor.shape[-1]
    a = tf.reshape(tensor, [-1, channels])
    n = a.shape[0]
    gram = tf.matmul(a, a, transpose_a = True)
    return gram
```

**get_features**-how the image and style_features are calculated

```
def get_features(image, model):
    output = model(image)
    features = [layer[0] for layer in output]
    return features
```

**gradient**

```
def get_gradient(loss, image):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(loss)
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, image)
    return grad
```

Comment: Did you try tape.watch(image) ?